# notifyDataSetChanged in a listfragment does nothing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listfragment

I have a listfragment with an adapter define like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  arrayList);
        setListAdapter(aa);
```

I 'm using this to add item to my list from an sqlite database

```
arrayList.add
```

the problem is that `notify data has change` does nothing (i m deleting element from the sqlite so i need to refresh the content of the arraylist)

i'm doing this :

```
aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: How are you reloading the adapter from SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a [StackOverflow anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/1150795) explaining in which case `notifyDataSetChanged()` method works. Here is quote from that answer:

> For an `ArrayAdapter`, `notifyDataSetChanged` only works if you use the
>   `add()`, `insert()`, `remove()`, and `clear()` on the `Adapter`.

I guess you are performing your operations on a database, but you are not performing any operations on the `Adapter` object. In your case, you should probably set Adapter every time, when you want to load fresh data.
You can use your existing code for this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  arrayList);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

In addition, you can wrap this code into a method like:

```
void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList);
```

and use it every time when you want to refresh your adapter.